# How priorities works in cadence-workflow?

Tags: cadence-workflow

I found this note in Activities description:

> Multiple priorities. One task list per priority and having a worker
>   pool per priority.

And I'm wondering how it works.

Is I understand right, that this all is implemented just through different tasks lists?
And for example if I want some workflows or activities to be processed with more priority, then what should I do?
Maybe is there some examples of how prioritization works?

Comment: We have ideas about explicitly supporting priorities in a single task list. But currently the best option is to use multiple task lists and have separate workers for each task list.

Comment: https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/53